# Connect to Gitlab in Docker Container in VM

Tags: docker, localhost, virtualbox

On a Windows 7 host, I have a Ubuntu guest inside virtualbox which runs a gitlab docker container. Inside the VM I can connect to the Gitlab inside the browser using localhost:80. How can I make the Gitlab reachable from the host?

So far I tried a port-forwanding in virtualbox which doesn't help. In my host with `ipconfig`, I see three IPs. One is the hosts public IP, the other two are the VirtualBox Host-Only Networks, which I can successfully ping.

Comment: Can you connect to your VM from host by using IP?

Comment: How can I try this?